# PHP Syntax error when i run file

Tags: php, syntax

I am new to PHP and I am getting the following PHP error when i run my PHP file.
A bit of help would be much appreciated, thanks very much in advance

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\arrays.php on line 21

Here is my code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> An empty html page </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- this is an html comment -->
            <!-- currently the body is empty -->
            <?php

            echo "<p>hello world</p>";

            $name = "Peter Pan";
            $address = "Neverland";
            $age = "14.75";

            $unnamed_lost_boys = array(4.5, 6, 7, 5.5, 5.25, 4, 7, 6.75);
            $named_lost_boys = array( "Tootles"=> 4.5,
                                    "Nibs"=>6,
                                    "Slightly"=>7.5);

            echo "The age of Nibs is $named_lost_boys['Nibs']";

            function print_details ($name, $age, $address)
            {
            echo "My name is $name, I'm from $address and I'm $age years old";
            echo "<br>";
            echo 'My name is '.$name.",I'm from ".$address." and I'm $age years old";
            echo "<br>";
            }
            print_details($name, $age, $address);

            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use arrays in string interpolation without wrapping them in curly braces; so use:

```
echo "The age of Nibs is {$named_lost_boys['Nibs']}";
```

Also see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "The age of Nibs is " . $named_lost_boys['Nibs'];
```